# Function in R that allows to control 2 variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Tourism <- function(...){
  tour%>% 
    filter(Country %in% c(...))%>%
    select(Country, `1995`:`2019`)%>%
    gather(key = "Year", value="Dollars", -Country)%>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Dollars, colour = Country, group = Country))  + 
    geom_line() +geom_point() +  
    scale_y_log10(label=dollar) + 
    ggtitle("Tourism Dollars") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
}
Tourism("Italy","Canada")
```

I have this code working pretty fine. However I would like to update this function to allow the user to set not only the country, but also the year shown in the graph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EobP1.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass two arguments to the function as vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

Tourism <- function(country, year){
  tour%>% 
    filter(Country %in% country) %>%
    select(Country, as.character(year)) %>%
    gather(key = "Year", value="Dollars", -Country)%>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Dollars, colour = Country, group = Country))  + 
    geom_line() +geom_point() +  
    scale_y_log10(label=dollar) + 
    ggtitle("Tourism Dollars") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
}

Tourism(c("Italy","Canada"), 1995:2019)
```